# How can I swap all instances of a variable in a Webi Report?

Tags: business-objects

I have a big, complex webi document in which a variable [Query1].[SomeVariable] is referenced numerous times in many reports and pages.

In the meanwhile some underlying data has changed, and I would like to create a variable [MyVar] on top of this [Query1].[SomeVariable] so I can modify it before use.

Is there a quick way to swap every instance of [Query1].[SomeVariable] with [MyVar], without manually searching and swapping it everywhere it is being used?

Comment: No quick way I'm afraid. You'll either have to do it manually or use the SDK. If it's a one-off, you're probably be better off doing it manually.

Comment: I was afraid you might say that. Well, here goes nothing...